# Python For Loop Error; Exception

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm new to python though have some experience with MATLAB. Any idea what's going on here? I'm trying to understand why this "exception" error is popping up. Thanks!

```
for i in range(1,len(yrsPOP)):
    tmpMax = yrsPOP.ix[i,:].max()
    tmpMin = min(yrsPOP.ix[i,:])
    tmp = tmpMax - tempMin
    change.append(tmp)

Error: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

It seems that the error occurs in the "tempMax" line. Help is appreciated!

Sincerely,
Python Rookie

Comment: What is the exact error (or errors) you are getting?

Comment: You do not have a `tempMin`, you have `tmpMin`. If it is not a typo in the snippet, it will cause an error.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comment that `yrsPOP` is a 2D array of values:

```
for row in yrsPOP:
    tmpMax = max(row)
    tmpMin = min(row)
    tmp = tmpMax - tmpMin
    change.append(tmp)
```

You should change the loop to `for row in yrsPOP.ix` if the values are stored in `yrsPOP.ix`.

### Issues with your original code

`1,` will become a tuple with a single element: `(1,)`, which is most likely not what you want as an index.

Using `[i:]` means "all items at index `i` and beyond".
If you want to get the item at index `i`, then use `[i]`.

You are subtracting `tempMin` instead of `tmpMin`, which will cause an error from accessing an undeclared variable.

You may also want to change the `tmpMax` to be `max(yrsPOP.ix[i:])`.

`len(yrsPOP)` is getting the number of items in `yrsPOP`, but then you are referencing `yrsPOP.ix`, is that correct?

Comment: Hey MattMS, thanks for the quick response, however yrsPOP is a 2-D array and my syntax above wanted to look across one entire row in yrsPOP, hence me choosing yrsPOP[i,:]... maybe I'm misunderstanding the proper syntax?

Comment: If it is a 2D array, then you should be able to access each row with `yrsPOP[i]`.

Comment: I have updated my code to what I think you are trying to do. Are the rows stored in `yrsPOP` or `yrsPOP.ix`?